# jQuery Mobile: applying method selectmenu on multiple select fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

On my jQuery Mobile page I would like to implement multiple filter select menus. It works totally fine with only one select menu and an id, but not with multiple.

**JSFiddle with my problem**:
http://jsfiddle.net/asvyY/40/

(By contrast, my fiddle with ONLY ONE select menu and a select menu id works: http://jsfiddle.net/asvyY/41/)

Error message:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'
```

My code:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form>
            <select class="filter-menu" data-native-menu="false">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>

             <select class="filter-menu" data-native-menu="false">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>

             <select class="filter-menu" data-native-menu="false">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){   
    $(".filter-menu").selectmenu( "refresh", true );
});

$.mobile.document
    .on("listviewcreate", "#filter-menu-menu", function (e) {
        var input,
        listbox = $("#filter-menu-listbox"),
            form = listbox.jqmData("filter-form"),
            listview = $(e.target);

        if (!form) {
            input = $("<input data-type='search'></input>");
            form = $("<form></form>").append(input);

            input.textinput();

            $("#filter-menu-listbox")
                .prepend(form)
                .jqmData("filter-form", form);
        }

        listview.filterable({
            input: input
        });
    })

    // The custom select list may show up as either a popup or a dialog,
    // depending how much vertical room there is on the screen. If it shows up
    // as a dialog, then the form containing the filter input field must be
    // transferred to the dialog so that the user can continue to use it for
    // filtering list items.
    //
    // After the dialog is closed, the form containing the filter input is
    // transferred back into the popup.
    .on("pagebeforeshow pagehide", "#filter-menu-dialog", function (e) {
        var form = $("#filter-menu-listbox").jqmData("filter-form"),
            placeInDialog = (e.type === "pagebeforeshow"),
            destination = placeInDialog ? $(e.target).find(".ui-content") : $("#filter-menu-listbox");

        form.find("input")

        // Turn off the "inset" option when the filter input is inside a dialog
        // and turn it back on when it is placed back inside the popup, because
        // it looks better that way.
        .textinput("option", "inset", !placeInDialog)
            .end()
            .prependTo(destination);
    });
```

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your question. Give some explanation.

Comment: Basically, I want the js fiddle I posted above (the first one) to work. I want a filterabe custom select to be realized for every select menu. I want the options list to look like this: http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/selectmenu-custom-filter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asvyY/46/

I deleted the following lines, because jqm automatically transforms the select-tag into a select-menu

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){   
    $(".filter-menu").selectmenu( "refresh", true );
});
```

The correct syntax for the listviewcreate event is:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "listviewcreate", function( event ) {} );
```

In the listviewcreate event i changed the id's to classes and initiated the listbox

```
listbox = $("<ul class='.filter-menu-listbox'></ul>");
```

I hope i could help you and sry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

You are running into problems because with multiple selectmenus you are using class names and no ids.

Give your selectmenus unique ids as well as the common class name. For the listviewcreate you can use the classnames and find other dom elements using closest()/find().etc.

```
$.mobile.document.on("listviewcreate", ".ui-selectmenu-list", function (e) {
    var input,
        listbox = $(this).closest(".ui-selectmenu"),
        form = listbox.jqmData("filter-form"),
        listview = $(this);

    if (!form) {
        input = $("<input data-type='search'></input>");
        form = $("<form></form>").append(input);
        input.textinput();

        listbox
            .prepend(form)
            .jqmData("filter-form", form);
    }

    listview.filterable({
        input: input
    });
})
```

In the case of a long list showing as a dialog. I am retrieving the base ID of the selectmenu and then using it to build selectors as needed:

```
.on("pagebeforeshow pagehide", ".ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog", function (e) {
    var id=$(this).prop("id").replace("-dialog","");

    var form = $("#" + id + "-listbox").jqmData("filter-form"),
        placeInDialog = (e.type === "pagebeforeshow"),
        destination = placeInDialog ? $(this).find(".ui-content") : $("#" + id + "-listbox");

    form.find("input")

    // Turn off the "inset" option when the filter input is inside a dialog
    // and turn it back on when it is placed back inside the popup, because
    // it looks better that way.
    .textinput("option", "inset", !placeInDialog)
        .end()
        .prependTo(destination);
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/asvyY/49/)**